# Creating a Custom Apache HTTP Client Redirect policy

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

Need little help, i might sound little confusing..

I am using Apache HTTP Client 4.5.1, I have a post url which needed some header to be used to call, once we call post url it return **303** and a get url, but As per HTTP Client redirect policy its automatically does redirect GET CALL but it send header also in the redirected GET CALL.

How do i override redirect policy of HTTP Client so that 303 redirect does not use header when calling redirect GET URL.

Any idea how to achieve this. I have already checked few option with redirect policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is [this line of code](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/RedirectExec.java#L123) in the `RedirectExec` request execution interceptor.

One should be able to prevent it from copying the original request headers by adding some harmless dummy request header with a custom redirect strategy

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {

            @Override
            public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(
                    HttpRequest request,
                    HttpResponse response,
                    HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
                HttpUriRequest redirectRequest = super.getRedirect(request, response, context);
                redirectRequest.addHeader("x-custom", "stuff");
                return redirectRequest;
            }
        })
        .build();
```

Comment: Yes correct. When I look into http client library I also came to this conclusion , modification of header can be done to the reference of request header by overriding getRedirect method. Thanks for the answer.